# How to set an instance attribute in parallel in a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to set an instance attribute by running an instance method in parallel. Let's say the attribute is initially an empty dictionary called `d`, and I want to update it in parallel by an instance method called `update_d`. I am currentely using `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random


class A():

    def __init__(self, n_jobs):

        self.d = dict()
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
        pool = Pool(self.n_jobs)
        pool.map(self.update_d, range(100))
        pool.close()

    def update_d(self, key):
        self.d[key] = random.randint(0, 100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(n_jobs=4)
    print(a.d)
```

However, the attribute is not updated after running `update_d` in parallel. I understand that it's because `multiprocessing.Pool` always folks the instance to individual processes. But I want to know what is the recommended way to do this in Python? **Note that I don't want to return anything from `update_d`, and we can assume that the code is written in a way that the individual processes won't conflict with each other.**

Edit: I just use dictionary as an example. I need a solution that allows the attribute to be any type of variable, e.g. a Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a `Manager` to create a `dict` for you. I still don't know how well the updates will work, whether there will be any race conditions.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import random


class A():

    def __init__(self, n_jobs, manager):
        self.d = manager.dict()
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
        pool = Pool(self.n_jobs)
        pool.map(self.update_d, range(100))
        pool.close()

    def update_d(self, key):
        self.d[key] = random.randint(0, 100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        a = A(n_jobs=4, manager=manager)
        print(a.d)
```

Comment: Does ``Manager`` only works for dictionaries? In my actualy case, I have a Pandas ``Dataframe`` object to be updated. I tried ``self.df = Manager().Dataframe()`` but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I think that `Manager` only has python native structures. (That is just `list` and `dict`)